# Calling service.js file from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I have a service file which needs to be called from the controller. Can someone please tell the code which should go in the controller to get this service file. Thank you.

---

**This is my service file code**

```
"use strict";

angular.module('jsFleet').service('trucksService',

       function () {
           this.getTrucks = function () {
               return trucks;
           };
           this.getTruck = function (truckID) {
               for (var i = 0, len = trucks.length; i < len; i++) {
                   if (trucks[i].truckID === parseInt(truckID)) {
                       return trucks[i];
                   }
               }
               return {};
           };
           var trucks = [
               {
                   truckID: 1,
                   status: Running,
                   destination: WPG,
                   alerts: Nothing
               },
                   {
                       truckID: 5,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 2,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 3,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 4,
                       status: Running,
                       destination: WPG,
                       alerts: Nothing
                   }
           ];

       });
```

---

**This is my controller code**

```
"use strict"; 

angular.module("jsFleet").controller("jsFleetController",
    ['$scope', 'trucksService', function ($scope, trucksService) {




    }]);
```

---

**This is my HTML code**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" align="center">TRUCKS</div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>TruckID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Dest.</th>
                    <th>Alerts</th>
                </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in trucks">
                <td>{{row.truckID}}</td>
                <td>{{row.status}}</td>
                <td>{{row.destination}}</td>
                <td>{{row.alerts}}</td>
            </tr>      
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"use strict"; 

angular.module("jsFleet").controller("jsFleetController", 
  ['$scope', 'trucksService', function ($scope, trucksService) {

     $scope.trucks = trucksService.getTrucks();

}]);
```

Comment: Hi Mihail, I tried that, its still not working. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error in the developer tools in your browser?

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=ext-modules%2FFleet%2FjsFleetController.js&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at qb (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.min.js:22:131)
    at Qa (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.min.js:22:218)
  .....
    at g (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.min.js:55:105)
    at http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.min.js:54:249(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107

Comment: Change your angular version from `localhost:51340/scripts/angular.min.js` to `localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js` because angular is minified and I can't understand the error.

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ext-modules/Fleet/jsFleetController.js' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=ext-modules%2FFleet%2FjsFleetController.js&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: The error is too lengthy to insert here. I'll break and send you. 
First half:
'Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ext-modules/Fleet/jsFleetController.js' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ng/areq?p0=ext-modules%2FFleet%2FjsFleetController.js&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:68:12
    at assertArg (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:1815:11)
    at assertArgFn (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:1825:3)
 at http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:9158:9'

Comment: Second half: 
' at A.link (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:8841:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:8335:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:7731:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:7611:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:51340/scripts/angular.js:7749:16)

Comment: Did you add `jsFleet`module in your app.js file?

Comment: `angular.module("app", ["ngRoute","jsFleet"]);`

Yes i did. It is giving same error still.

Comment: Hi Mihail, can you please check this question and tell where the mistake is? Thank you.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/34668416/5724169