# Linking one controller to another to call service on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click

I have two templates with respective controllers and service files. One template's(fleetListTemplate)  controller(fleetListController) loads data from its service file(fleetService) and displays in its view(fleetListTemplate).

When this happens, and I click on one of the loaded data from fleetService, I should link fleetListController to fleetSummaryController to get data from its service file (fleetSummaryService) and display in fleetSummaryTemplate view.

Can someone please help me with the coding? Thank you.

The following are the respective modules, templates, controllers and service files.

**fleetListModule**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetListModule", []);
```

---

**fleetListTemplate**

```
<div class="panel1 panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" align="center">TRUCKS</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">

        <tr>
            <th>TruckID</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Dest.</th>
            <th>Alerts</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="truck in trucks" ng-click="summaryData()">
            <td>{{truck.truckID}}</td>
            <td>{{truck.status}}</td>
            <td>{{truck.destination}}</td>
            <td>{{truck.alerts}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

---

**fleetListController**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetListModule").controller("fleetListController",
    ['$scope', 'fleetsService', 
        function ($scope, fleetsService) {

            $scope.trucks = fleetsService.getTrucks();


            $scope.summaryData = function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('obtainSummary');
            }

        }]);
```

---

**fleetSummaryModule**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetSummaryModule", []);
```

---

**fleetSummaryTemplate**

```
<div class="panel2 panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Summary</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">

        <tr ng-repeat="summary in truckSummary">
            <td>Truck ID: {{summary.truckID}}</td>
            <td>Trailer ID: {{summary.trailerID}}</td>
            <td>Driver ID: {{summary.driverID}}</td>
            <td>Truck Number: {{summary.truckNumber}}</td>
            <td>Trailer Number: {{summary.trailerNumber}}</td>
            <td>Insurance Due Date: {{summary.insuranceDueDate}}</td>
            <td>Maintenance Due Date: {{summary.maintenanceDueDate}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

---

**fleetSummaryController**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetSummaryModule").controller("fleetSummaryController",
    ['$scope', 'fleetSummaryService',
        function ($scope, fleetSummaryService) {
        $scope.$on('obtainSummary', function (event, args) {

            $scope.truckSummary = fleetSummaryService.getSummary();
        })

        }]);
```

---

**fleetSummaryService**

```
"use strict";

angular.module("fleetSummaryModule").service("fleetSummaryService",

       function () {
           this.getSummary = function () {
               return summary;
           };
           this.getSummary = function (truckID) {
               for (var i = 0, len = truckSummary.length; i < len; i++) {
                   if (truckSummary[i].truckID === parseInt(truckID)) {
                       return truckSummary[i];
                   }
               }
               return {};
           };
           var truckSummary = [
               {
                   truckID: 1,
                   trailerID: '123',
                   driverID: 'Alex123',
                   truckNumber: 'hyt 583',
                   trailerNumber: 'xyz213',
                   insuranceDueDate: '25-12-2015',
                   maintenanceDueDate: '31-12-2015'

               },
                   {
                       truckID: 2,
                       trailerID: '456',
                       driverID: 'Alex123',
                       truckNumber: 'hyt 583',
                       trailerNumber: 'xyz213',
                       insuranceDueDate: '25-12-2015',
                       maintenanceDueDate: '31-12-2015'

                   },
                   {
                       truckID: 3,
                       trailerID: '789',
                       driverID: 'Alex123',
                       truckNumber: 'hyt 583',
                       trailerNumber: 'xyz213',
                       insuranceDueDate: '25-12-2015',
                       maintenanceDueDate: '31-12-2015'
                    }
           ];

       });
```

Comment: To share data between controllers, use a service to set/get that data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: I dont want to share data between controllers. When I click in one template I want to send message from one controller to another to load data from its respective service and display in its respective view.

Comment: You could $broadcast an event from $rootScope and listen for it using $scope.$on: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Comment: I am trying that method. But I'm missing something in my code which is not working. So I thought if someone here could help me out ;)

Comment: @GauravRam Hi, do you want to send a list or something like that from one controller to other, but you want to do that by a common service i think, right?

Comment: Hi Maher, thanks for the example. The one I coded above to works, its just I had a mistake in my summary service file, which I corrected and works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This simple example show to you how to share data between 2 controllers "in one app"
>   using common service.

```js
angular.module("app", []);

        ///controller1
        angular.module("app").controller("controller1", function ($scope, service) {
            $scope.lists = [
                { name: "maher" },
                { name: "Gaurav Ram" },
                { name: "Shaun Scovil" }
            ];

            $scope.send = function () {
                service.set("lists", $scope.lists); //set(key, value)
                $scope.lists = []; //optional
            }

        });

        ///controller2
        angular.module("app").controller("controller2", function ($scope, service) {
            $scope.lists = [];

            //get data from broadcast on the root
            service.get("lists"); // get(key)

            //set data
            $scope.resive = function () {
                if (angular.isUndefined($scope.broadcast)) {
                    $scope.alert = "No data to resive!";
                } else {
                    $scope.alert = null;
                    $scope.lists = $scope.broadcast;
                }
            }
        });

        ///service
        angular.module("app").service("service", function ($rootScope) {
            this.set = function (key, value) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast(key, value);
            }

            this.get = function (key) {
                $rootScope.$on(key, function (event, data) {
                    $rootScope.broadcast = data;
                });
            }
        });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="controller1" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>controller 1</h1>
        </div>

        <button ng-click="send()" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <br/>
        <div class="alert alert-info" ng-if="lists.length == 0">Data <b>sent</b> to controller 2, click Resive button to get data</div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="list-group-item" ng-bind="list.name"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="controller2" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>controller 2</h1>
        </div>

        <button ng-click="resive()" class="btn btn-success">Resive</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <br />
        <div class="alert alert-info" ng-bind="alert" ng-if="alert"></div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li ng-repeat="list in lists" class="list-group-item" ng-bind="list.name"></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```