# Access routeprovider controller from child controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a routeprovider that assigns a controller to a different route.

```
.when('/page/:id', {
  templateUrl: '/page/overview.ejs',
  title: __('pageTitle'),
  controller: 'PageCtrl'
}
```

and in the `overview.ejs` I have something like this:

```
<div>
     <div ng-controller="SubPageCtrl">
     ....
     </div>
</div>
```

The question is: how do I access the property of `PageCtrl` in `SubPageCtrl`?

I tried to do this, but it does not work:

```
function PageCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "testing";
}

function SubPageCtrl($scope) {
    console.log($scope.$parent.test);
    console.log($scope.test)
}
```

Both of them print out `undefined`. Does anybody know how I can make it work?

**Edit:**

It turned out I put the
    $scope.test = "testing";
in a callback of a asynchronous call, so the data is not ready when I call the console.log.

Other than that, it should be just what Vignesh's response below

Comment: You can't pass data like that in angular, for that you have to use $broadcast to share data between 2 controller.

Comment: i  answered this question, look at this [share data between 2 controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668416/linking-one-controller-to-another-to-call-service-on-ng-click/34702780#34702780)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, Maher. Although, this is just a simple parent-to-child structure. We can just use the share scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can try this

In **PageCtrl**
Declare $scope.test as an object.
$scope.test = {data: 'test'}

In **SubPageCtrl** you can directly able to access the '$scope.test.data'. You don't need to use the $parent.

Make use of prototype chaining.