# update url angularJS

Tags: angularjs, url

I want to select a person from the list and update the URL to get a shareable URL.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="ctrl.persons as person" ng-click="ctrl.details(person)>{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>

<div class="details">{{ctrl.active_person.name}}</div>
```

in the controller

```
vm.persons = [{id: 1, name: "john"}, {id: 2, name: "george"}, {id: 3, name: "michael"}];
vm.details = function(person) {
    $location.path('/persons/' + person.id);
    vm.active_person = person;
}
```

I´m successfully updating the URL when I select a person from the list.
te problem is that If I reload the page the selection is lost. 
how can I make vm.active_person = **the person with the id in the url** ?

notes: In this example I added an array with 3 persons but in the *real* code that array is coming from a service (with many many many persons)

thanks so much!

Comment: Which router are you using?

Comment: I´m using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Go through tutorial...shows how to use `$routeParams`. Use that to filter data for person needed

Comment: If you have the person Id that mean you can get user information in next page from your database, it's normal if after changing the url you lose the selected person

Comment: you can use this way [linking-one-controller-to-another-to-call-service-on-ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668416/linking-one-controller-to-another-to-call-service-on-ng-click/34702780#34702780)

Comment: Are you using HTML5 mode?

Comment: as javascript is stateless and angular too is stateless. you can write a service that will use sessionStorage to store and retrieve your data. so When you are selecting person you can store that into sessionStorage and when you are refreshing you can get the stored person data and update the url as well