# angularjs1.5+ component doesn't receive broadcast event ($on doesn't work)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angular-broadcast

I was writing some code and realized that angularjs1.5+ component doesn't actually receive the `$scope.$broadcast` event, means `$scope.$on` never run in component controller function.

Though I was able to `$emit` the event from the component controller and received by the parent controller by `$on`, but it just doesn't listen for the broadcast event.

**broadcast** from parent: `$scope.$broadcast('parentEvnt', [1,2,3]);`

but **NOT** recieved in component  : `$scope.$on('parentEvnt', function(event, data){ \\`

I created this [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fhttD8ICRzd4AUrYEuLh?p=preview) to show the issue.

Searched some articles and as well on SO but didn't found any answer, and tried with `$rootScope.$broadcast` that didn't help too.

and, If it is not possible, then what's the best way to notify the component from any random place in app?

Comment: Hi, maybe this helps you [linking-one-controller-to-another-to-call-service-on-ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668416/linking-one-controller-to-another-to-call-service-on-ng-click/34702780#34702780)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you are `broadcast`ing the event even before your child controllers initialize and start listening to those event. Hence, it doesn't matter whether you use `$scope` or `$rootScope` to `broadcast` :)

For instance, I changed your `broadcast` to have it inside a `$timeout` with 2 seconds, it would work as expected.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('parentEvnt', [1,2,3]);
}, 2000);
```

Though, you would ideally want to have it on button click or some other scenario.

[**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/VqsTh0rAIsHWcxG50SjE?p=preview)

Comment: @anoop np, glad it helped a bit :)