# Angular $emit, $on not working

Tags: angularjs, addeventlistener, eventemitter

I'm trying to learn Angular event listening. After a user clicks a button, the controller queries the database and returns a value in the button's handler. I'm having trouble passing this value to the `$scope` so that other functions can access the data.

First question: is this what event listeners are for? Is there another way to do what I want?

Next question: why doesn't this code work:

```
app.controller('EmitterCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("Emitter controller.");

  $scope.buttonClick = function() {
    console.log("Button clicked!"); // this works
    $scope.$emit('myEvent', 'Clicked!'); // child $scope
  };

  $scope.$on('myEvent'), function(event, data) { // parent $scope
    console.log("I heard it!"); // doesn't work
    console.log(event);
    console.log(word);
  };

});

<div ng-controller="EmitterCtrl">
  <button type="button" ng-click="buttonClick()">
    Click me!
  </button>
</div>
```

The user clicks the button, the event handler fires in the controller. The handler creates a child `$scope` so `$emit` sends the event to the parent `$scope`. Then the event isn't emitted, or the listener doesn't catch it.

Comment: maybe this helps you [Linking one controller to another to call service on ng-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668416/linking-one-controller-to-another-to-call-service-on-ng-click/34702780#34702780)

Comment: I did some testing and my example has only one $scope, so $emit and $on are on the same $scope. In the project that I'm working on, the handlers ($scope functions) appear to create their own child scopes, but now I see that this is wrong. There must be something else wrong with my project.

Answer (score 5):

> $emit dispatches an event upwards ... $broadcast dispatches an event
>   downwards

**Detailed explanation**

`$rootScope.$emit` only lets other `$rootScope` listeners catch it. This is good when you don't want every `$scope` to get it. Mostly a high level communication. Think of it as adults talking to each other in a room so the kids can't hear them.

`$rootScope.$broadcast` is a method that lets pretty much everything hear it. This would be the equivalent of parents yelling that dinner is ready so everyone in the house hears it.

`$scope.$emit` is when you want that `$scope` and all its parents and `$rootScope` to hear the event. This is a child whining to their parents at home (but not at a grocery store where other kids can hear).

`$scope.$broadcast` is for the `$scope` itself and its children. This is a child whispering to its stuffed animals so their parents can't hear.